# Symfony Entity values not passed

Tags: php, symfony

I have created an entity `WorkGroup`, and also have an entity `User` which are annotated in this way.

```
class WorkGroup{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /*  
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $sworkgroup;
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="user", mappedBy="workgroup",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $users;
```

As per the `User` Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WorkGroup", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sgid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $workgroup;
```

In the User Form I have embedded an `WorkGroup` form.

```
$builder->add('workgroup', new WorkGroupType());
```

`WorkGroupType` which embedded:

```
$builder->add('sworkgroup', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
    'KSI' => 'KSI',
    '3CIS' => '3CIS',),
    'choices_as_values' => true, 
));
```

When the form is submitted the `sworkgroup` field is `NULL`.
My question is how to pass the value from the form into `sworkgroup`.

Comment: Why field is called `sworkgroup` and entity field is `workgroup`? How can Symfony understand that these items are connected?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is EntityType. You should replace your current `$builder->add('workgroup', new WorkGroupType());` line in your User Form like this:

```
->add('environments', EntityType::class, [
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => false,
    'class' => WorkGroup::class,
    'choice_label'  => 'sworkgroup'
 ])
```

then your select field will work as expected!